# .com domain registered to 127.0.0.1

Tags: dns

There is some dot com domain someone has registed and pointed to 127.0.0.1.  Something like myserver.com.

I saw this in an answer on a stackoverflow question - but the name of the domain has totally escaped me.  Can anyone remember that domain name??

Comment: This should really go to serverfault.com

Comment: @SigTerm - why were my updates rolled back?

Comment: @TesterTurnedDeveloper: I haven't noticed that you're the OP, plus it wasn't a question, so I interpreted it as an "invalid edit". If it answers your question, post it as an answer instead - nobody will have a problem with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this one. [somesite.com](http://somesite.com)

Edit: This site has since changed ownership and is no longer useful. Stupid ad pages.

Comment: This might have been the SO question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958504/redirect-localhost-through-proxy

Comment: I remember seeing it a while ago on SO, but I don't think that was the one I saw.

Comment: I think this is the one I first saw it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562954/public-wildcard-domain-name-to-resolve-to-127-0-0-1

Comment: Who owns the mail server for somesite.com?  (Oops, this question belongs on serverfault.)

Answer (score 5):

I run one at [loop.iambroken.com](http://loop.iambroken.com).

There are a few other services [at that website](http://iambroken.com/), too.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using windows, put

`anything.com    127.0.0.1`

in `%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: On UNIX-like operating systems (Linux, Mac OS X, etc) the file is simply /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 2):

It is called "localhost".

Comment: That's not a .com domain.  But +1 anyway.  :)!

Answer (score 1):

A similar cool service: http://readme.localtest.me/. You can download their CA signed SSL cert to install on your own box.

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is a local address that points to your computer.

Generally, you use `localhost` to access this address. I'm not sure if it is by default in your `hosts` file, but if it isn't, it is generally configured to point to your computer by applications that run servers locally.

My guess is that no one really **owns** the TLD, and that is simply put there for a placeholder.

Comment: It allows having an HTTPS website with other content served up from the local machine via HTTPS and not have the browser complain.

Answer (score 0):

When I was a "child", spending my time on IRC, I used to give people asking for a computer to crack a domain of this kind. I don't know the reason for this, but clearly the DNS has been configured to return 127.0.0.1 as the address for that domain.