# Why is an external domain name displaying my localhost site?

Tags: dns, localhost

I have a localhost set up on my Windows 7 computer for developing a website. When I accidentally spelled GoDaddy wrong and typed goodaddy.com into Chrome and hit enter it displayed my localhost site. It didn't redirect me. The address bar still said goodaddy.com. When I viewed the source of the page it was just the source of my localhost site but the address bar still displayed view-source:goodaddy.com

I tried ctrl+f5 to refresh it, I also tried navigating to goodaddy.com on a private browsing window in Chrome and it still displayed my localhost site. Then I tried it in Firefox and Safari, and they are also displaying the localhost site while keeping goodaddy.com in the address bar.

According to WhoIs information this is a registered domain name. And when I navigate to it from a different computer it just says 'Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to goodaddy.com'

So why are all the browsers on my computer treating this domain a if it was localhost instead of a domain that it cannot connect to like it is? I don't understand at all.

Edit: Also if I typed a nonsensical domain that definitely does not exist (example: jkdkfs.com) Chrome properly just says 'Oop! Google Chrome could not connect to jkdkfs.com' instead of showing me my localhost site. How did this one domain get mapped to my localhost site across all browsers?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same thing. The domain appears to be registered by Moniker DNS (www.moniker.com) to go to 127.0.0.1. See there - http://whoisrequest.org/whois/goodaddy.com

Why? Who knows :)

Other SO thread(s) on the subject - [.com domain registered to 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219510/com-domain-registered-to-127-0-0-1)