# How to intercept local server web requests using Burp in Internet Explorer

Tags: localhost, burp

I have properly configured **Burp** to intercept at a proxy location at

- 127.0.0.1:9090

My Internet Explorer proxy settings are as follows:

[image: Internet Options -> Connections -> Proxy Settings]

Also I have a webserver named WebGoat running in http://localhost:8080/WebGoat/

All the requests are not being intercepted by Burp, in any way.

What Should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding a '.' after "localhost". This should solve your problem.

eg.

```
http://localhost.:8080/WebGoat/
```

This will force the localhost to use the same proxy settings as one would with an internet connection/adapter.

Comment: This is not always applicable - what if you're intercepting a thick client where you cannot modify the URL?

Comment: In that case, refrain from using IE. Chrome, Firefox handle traffic just fine without this.

Comment: Alright thanks, in your previous comment, you said you don't need to use this for firefox and chrome. How did you do it? For me, I need to add the . even on Firefox.

Comment: @Rockstar5645 Hey sorry about the wait. Its been a while since this answer has been posted. At which point chrome and firefox could have made significant changes.

But I suspect its probably something to do with your proxy settings. Were you able to resolve it at all?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.
I was trying to get Burp to work using dvwa (This is on windows using xampp)
Same thing happened, I search 127.0.0.1/dvwa no traffic was intercepted.

Fix for me was, use your LAN IP in the URL bar not 127.0.0.1

Hope this helps

Comment: My local IP is: 10.0.0.102 and it wasn't working (http://10.0.0.102:8081/WebGoat), it said `This site can’t be reached` and `10.0.0.102 refused to connect.`

Answer (score 5):

Using IE9 and above version:

1. Internet Options -> Connections Tab
2. LAN settings
3. Under Proxy server section

   Click Advanced
4. Under "Do not use proxy server for addresses beginning with:"

   Add Exceptions

   `<-loopback>`

[image: loopback]

Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fiddler/2011/02/10/fiddler-and-the-ie9-release-candidate/

Answer (score 5):

**Steps to follow to Intercept Localhost Traffic with Burp Suite Mozilla Firefox:**

1. Go to Mozilla and type **about:config**
2. Accept the risk and continue.
3. Now, search **network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost** and set the value from false to **true**
4. Send request from the localhost, it will start intercepting

Answer (score 0):

burp suite - option - connections - upstream proxy servers - Destination host = *, Proxy host = 127.0.0.1, Proxy port = 8080
http://localhost.:8080/WebGoat
http://127.0.0.1.:8080/WebGoat

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to fix this as stated above. Here is what I did.

Open the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) (you need admin privilege) and add an entry like this

> 127.0.0.1 example.com

It means example.com points to IP address 127.0.0.1

Now you can access the localhost application through any browser using `example.com` and Burp Suite will successfully intercept the request.

[image]